# Ng-include header with materializecss

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, materialize

CodePen:
https://codepen.io/raynerprogramming/project/editor/ArNmxN/

I'm trying to split out my header into a separate HTML file and include it with ng-include.  However, I can't seem to get the sideNav() call to actually work in this setup.  If I bring the header.html file into the index.html.  It works as intended.

I've tried various events to hook into before calling the sideNav() without any luck.

- angular.element(document).ready(function () {})
- $rootScope.$on("$includeContentLoaded", function(event,
- templateName){}); plain jquery $(function() {})

The codepen also includes the working copy, index_working.html.

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
  <title>Test</title>
  <!-- CSS  -->     
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/css/materialize.min.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/0.98.2/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="/app.js"></script> 
</head>
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="testController">
  <div ng-include="'header.html'"></div>
  HELLO WORLD
</body>
<script></script>
</html>
```

header.html:

```
<nav class="grey darken-3" role="navigation">
  <div class="nav-wrapper container">
    <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
    <li><a class="dropdown-button" href="#!" data-activates="srvDropdown">Test<i class="material-icons right">arrow_drop_down</i></a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html">{{data}}</a></li>
    </ul>    
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
      <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a href="test.html">test</a></li>
    </ul>
    <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
  </div>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id="srvDropdown" class="dropdown-content">
    <li><a href="test.html">TEST</a></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Angular:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[])
.controller('testController',function($scope){
$scope.data='test';    
$scope.init = function(){
  $(function () {
    $('.button-collapse').sideNav();
  });
  }
$scope.init();

});
```

Comment: This approach is problematic. You should be using a routing framework (such as _angular-ui-router_) to accomplish this. Alternately, if your header is always the same, just use an element directive